# Selecting foreign key on ERD

Tags: foreign-keys, primary-key, erd

I am creating a simple ERD for a school project and have to have a PK and FK, I can't work out what I would do as the FK as the attributes are not names the same. I can only have these two tables otherwise it's over splitting. Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's my first ERD and I am slowly getting my head around it. Thank you.

Image attached: 
[ERD diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D1dN.png)

Comment: Both the home and away team IDs can be foreign keys in the fixture table, both pointing to the team table.  What is your exact question?

Comment: Okay sorry didn't see it that way, that is great thank you for your help. So I can have two FK in the Fixtures table as well as the PK?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not, perhaps barring some limitations of your specific database.  Your fixture table also looks relatively normalized to me.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your help! I know it's a super simple ERD just getting my head around it all. Thank you.